# Error while installing any plugin

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using the latest version of Ionic and just getting started with the Ionic Framework. I am trying to add plugins to my projects but always I gets error something like as shown in image. I have checked my internet connection and tried to install some other plugins also but I get the same error always.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling cordova

```
npm uninstall cordova -g
```

and installing latest version

```
npm install -g cordova
```